# Does anyone know of a good tutorial for the basics of 3d graphics programming (from scratch, not Direct3d or OpenGL)

Tags: graphics, 3d

I'm looking for some material on how homogeneous coordinates, perspectives, and projections work in 3d graphics on a basic level. An approach using programming would be stellar. I've been searching around and my searches are convoluted with OpenGL, Direct3d, and material more concerned with the mathematical proofs than the actual application. Does anyone know of a place where I could find this information (online access preferred)?

Comment: Mm, I'm assuming you have a good reason for it, but it's like asking "Does anyone know of a good tutorial for the basics of Windows programming (from scratch, in assembler, not C/MFC/something-a-little-higher-levelled)".

Comment: some related Answers of mine  [Understanding Homogenous Transform Matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) and [Mathematically compute a simple graphics pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21100338/2521214) and [convex polygon rasterization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19078088/2521214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to look for pre-OpenGL textbooks like Foley and van Dam's [Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice in C (2nd Edition).](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406)

In particular, Ch 11 Representing Curves and Surfaces and Ch 15 Visible-Surface Determination would be relevant, but earlier material on how to draw lines and shapes would also be useful if you are truly doing everything from scratch. Something as simple as drawing a line is non-trivial if you think about it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found a lot of great 3D graphics programming information on [Charles Petzold's book blog](http://charlespetzold.com/blog/toc.html). The 3D code is mostly in XAML, so it is simple enough to understands the basics without too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the following two books together right now to learn WPF's 3D graphics model and the underlying math at the same time.  Both books are outstanding in my opinion, though it may not be what you're looking for:

[3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556229119)

[3D Programming for Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623945) (this is a WPF 3d book, though the title doesn't reflect it)

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be the [OpenGL Programming Guide](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/) (Red Book). You can read it online (albeit an older edition) and is full of examples (actual working code).