# how to rasterize rotated rectangle (in 2d by setpixel)

Tags: c, algorithm, 2d, graph-algorithm, rasterize

I have got a four 2d vertices A B C D of rotated rectangle,
I need to rasterize/draw it (efficiently) in pixelbufer
with setpixel(x,y,color)

how to do it?

i was trying with some code like

```
    // convertilg a b c d do up down left right, 
    // calculating some dx_left dx_right on y--
    // etc (frustrating on special cases when there are 2 up_y vertices in same line etc)


    for(;;)
    {

     drawhorizontalline(y, xstart, xend, color);

     if(y==downy) break;

     y--;
     xstart+=dxstart;
     xend+=dxend;

     if(y==lefty)  dxstart = dxright;
     if(y==righty) dxend = dxleft;

     }
```

but it is most frustrating (terribly bug prone and most frustrating)
i am really tired of debuging this all day yesterday and i need to find 
maybe some working code rather than to try to debug this

Comment: You'd normally start by implementing a line drawing algorithm (e.g., Bresenham's), and then invoke it four times, one for each line of the rectangle. Googling for "Bresenham's algorithm" (or something similar) should turn up a *lot* of results.

Comment: I need filled rectangle - and rasterizning by horizontal lines would be faster - like in my approach - but im tired of debug this

Comment: [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7870533/968261) will help you get 95-99% of the work.

Comment: Filling a rectangle with lots of calls to `setpixel` is usually not very efficient.

Comment: @grunge fightr well you seen inactive at this question for a while do you still need an better answer or you have done it already. If you need specific code comment me with what params you need (color,texture,...)

Answer (score 12):

To fill your rectangle handle it as closed convex polygon (almost the same as triangle filling)

1. **order your points to match winding rule**

   so there are lines **AB BC CD DA** or reverse
2. **create left and right buffer**

   address is `y`-coordinate, its an array of `x`-positions and if needed also array of `color,texture coordinates,...`. for starters:

   ```
   int buf_x0[ys],buf_x1[ys];
   ```

   where `ys` is screen `y`-resolution
3. **implement any draw line algorithm**

   but instead of draw to screen just store `x` coordinate of pixel to buffer.

   - instead of: `setpixel(x,y,color);` do: `buf_x?[y]=x;`.

   Which buffer is the destination depends on the line `Y` direction

   - if `dy<0` then fill `buff_x0`
   - if `dy>0` then fill `buff_x1`
   - if `dy==0` then `buf_x0[y]=min(x)` and `buf_x1[y]=max(x)`

   **Beware you have to sort the line endpoints by x coordinate before rasterizing** to avoid seams/holes in meshes caused by different pixels produced for reversed endpoints lines.
4. **apply this line algorithm to all border lines of polygon (AB,BC,CD,DA)**

   after this the buffers contains start and end `x`-positions of your horizontal lines
5. **fill the rectangle on screen**

   ```
   for (y=min(Ay,By,Cy,Dy);y<=max(Ay,By,Cy,Dy);y++)
    draw_horizontal_line(y,buf_x0[y],buf_x1[y],color);
   ```

Image for clarity (taken from my lectures on low level computer graphics)

[image: border buffer creation]

**image description:**

- vertical rectangles represents the border buffers `buf_x0[],buf_x1[]`
- **clockwise winding rule** ensures the destination buffer. If its coded properly than `buf_x0[y] <= buf_x1[y]` so draw of horizontal line colapses to single `for` loop

Also se these:

- [simple 2D raster C++ example of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062479/2521214)
- [simple 3D voxel grid C++ example of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74251621/2521214)

Comment: here is nice triangle fill implementation (the same approach as mine) http://stackoverflow.com/a/7870925/2521214

Comment: Thanks @spektre - great algorithm!