# Knowing if middle vertex is left or right when sorting a triangle vertices by Y?

Tags: c++, sorting, math, rendering

I'm reading [Chris Hecker's Texture Mapping articles](http://chrishecker.com/images/4/41/Gdmtex1.pdf) and for the life of me I can't understand how he's using the Y order of vertices to determine if the middle vertex was on the left or right.

Sorting code:

```
    if (Y0 < Y1)
    {
        if (Y2 < Y0)
        {
            Top = 2; Middle = 0; Bottom = 1;
            MiddleCompare = 0; BottomCompare = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Top = 0;
            if (Y1 < Y2)
            {
                Middle = 1; Bottom = 2;
                MiddleCompare = 1; BottomCompare = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                Middle = 2; Bottom = 1;
                MiddleCompare = 2; BottomCompare = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Y2 < Y1)
        {
            Top = 2; Middle = 1; Bottom = 0;
            MiddleCompare = 1; BottomCompare = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Top = 1;
            if (Y0 < Y2)
            {
                Middle = 0; Bottom = 2;
                MiddleCompare = 3; BottomCompare = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                Middle = 2; Bottom = 0;
                MiddleCompare = 2; BottomCompare = 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then he writes:

```
if (BottomCompare > MiddleCompare)
{
    MiddleIsLeft = 0;
    Left = &TopToBottom; Right = &TopToMiddle;
}
else
{
    MiddleIsLeft = 1;
    Left = &TopToMiddle; Right = &TopToBottom;
}
```

My questions:

- How are we relying on the Y order to tell if the middle vertex is left or right? It's really confusing cause the sorting is only done on Y, there was no mention of X.
- Obviously, the `BottomCompare` and `MiddleCompare` variables exist to achieve the comparison. In the first half of the comparison (the 'if'), `MiddleCompare` equals `Middle` and `BottomCompare` equals `Bottom`. But in the second half (the 'else') `BottomCompare` equals `3` when `Bottom` equals `0`, and `MiddleCompare` equals `3` when `Middle` equals `0`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is:

1. **The polygon winding rule.**

   The vertexes of triangle/polygon should be in specific order **CW/CCW**.
2. **You should deciding target side for line not for point.**

   Deciding single point would be mistake as some points are in both sides.

So for example if:

- order is **CW**
- `x+` axis goes right
- `y+` axis goes down
- vertexes are `A,B,C`

[image: example]

Then you decide the **left/right** side from the change in `y` axis. So while rasterizing any of the outlines (`AB,BC,CA`) you look at the `y` change between first and last point. For example `AB` line:

```
dy = (B.y-A.y)
if (dy> 0) right
if (dy< 0) left
if (dy==0) both
```

For more info see related **Q/A** [closed convex polygon filling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078088/2521214).

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: I am too late after Spektre's answer, but I do not want to throw away my hand-drawn picture :)*

It seems you have missed important part: triangle vertices are numbered in clockwise manner. So knowing of Y-order allows to reject impossible variants.

And value 3 of *Compare is used to provide cyclic order.

Example for `Y0 < Y1`. For clockwise order point 2 may lie in one of marked regions (at right hand of P0-P1 vector):

[image]