# Why do polygons have to be simple and convex?

Tags: opengl, graphics, polygon, convex

Why is it so important that polygons you push through the pipeline be "simple" and "convex"?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to OpenGL? I would assume that it makes life for the graphics engine a lot easier and more efficient. You can break down a complex and/or non-convex polygon into several simple, convex polygons.

Comment: Yes specifically to OpenGL

Comment: @KaylieTess Probably because a convex polygon be broken down into triangles with ease. If the polygon is concave this is more complicated.

Comment: Convex polygons are directly renderable ... see [how to rasterize rotated rectangle (in 2d by setpixel)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078088/2521214) on the other hand convex polygons are not as that would lead to wrong output ...

Comment: @Rabbid76 convex polygons do not need to be broken to triangles ... they can be rendered directly with the same scanline interpolation algorithm ... however highly parallel implementations might prefer triangles as they can be done in parallel using barycentric coordinates and inside 2D BBOX test instead

Comment: @KaylieTess what exactly do you mean by "simple" polygon?

Answer (score -1):

In the OpenGL compatibility profile (as modern OpenGL no longer has a `GL_POLYGON` primitive), polygons other than convex polygons are not guaranteed to be rendered correctly (10.1.16) because an implementation is required only to store "at least two processed vertices" per polygon primitive — "a convex polygon can be rasterized as its vertices arrive, before all of them can be specified" (10.1.5). This goes back to the client-server nature of OpenGL (2.1).