# Algorithm for finding grid cells contained in arbitrary rotated rectangle (rasterizing)

Tags: c#, algorithm, rasterizing, range-tree

I'm looking for an algorithm that can compute all grid cells occupied by an arbitrary rectangle in 2d space in a defined area. The rectangle is defined by it's 4 corner coordinates. In the picture below I marked two of them as red, the coordinates of the grid cells are in black. I'm looking for a generic case that also covers unaligned grids (center of grid != center of underlying coodinate system), but converting between Cell coordinates <=> Coordinate system is trivial and already implemented. All cells are squares.

The calculation is done thousands in very short amounts of time and needs to be as fast as possible.

[image]

What I'm doing right now:

Right now I'm calculating the edges of the rectangle (AB, BC, CD, DA) and sample them at `sampleRate = cellWidth / 4` intervals. To find the middle cells I construct new lines from `AB + sampleRate * x` to `CD + sampleRate * x` and sample those lines again at `sampleRate`. I put all cells that I find at each sampled point into a HashSet to remove duplicates. But I feel this is increadibly inefficient.

I also thought about grabbing all cells in my relevant area into a buffer and generate a **range tree** or **index tree**. Then I could queue the bounds of the rectangle and get all contained cells at O(log n+m), but I'm not sure how to implement that and I can't even find any C# range tree implementations.

My knowledge in computer graphics is very rusty, but shouldn't there be an easy geometrical approach that works without sampling?

Comment: Why not see the rectangle as two triangles? There are a lot of well known algorithms for fast filling of a triangle.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem As I said, my CG is pretty limited. What would those algorithms be?

Comment: see https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/wiki/Lesson-2:-Triangle-rasterization-and-back-face-culling

Comment: and https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/filled-triangles.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to rasterize rotated rectangle (in 2d by setpixel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061146/how-to-rasterize-rotated-rectangle-in-2d-by-setpixel)

Comment: convex polygons can be rasterized without triangulation ... see [how to rasterize rotated rectangle (in 2d by setpixel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061146/how-to-rasterize-rotated-rectangle-in-2d-by-setpixel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points you care about are marked with a dot in the image below. Each point represents either the minimum X value or the maximum X value for a given Y value. For each Y value, the X value is easily calculated from the equation for a line:

x = x<sub>0</sub> + (y - y<sub>0</sub>)(x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>0</sub>) / (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>)

Note that an axis-aligned rectangle (where (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>) is 0) needs to be handled as a special (but trivial) case.

Also note that once you've computed the first X value along an edge of the rectangle, the other X values are equally spaced. The spacing is the inverse of the slope of the line. So the division
M = (x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>0</sub>) / (y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>0</sub>)
only needs to be done once, and then repeatedly added to the X value. For example, after calculating the X coordinate for point A in the image, the X coordinate for point B is B<sub>x</sub> = A<sub>x</sub> + M. And the X coordinate for point C is C<sub>x</sub> = B<sub>x</sub> + M.

Once you have the min and max X values for each Y value, it's a simple `for` loop to get all the cells that have that Y value.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Where do I get the Y values from?

Comment: @sollniss The top Y coordinate is 4.554, and the bottom Y coordinate is -1.2. So the Y values you care about are 4 to -1.

Comment: @sollniss I missed the part where the grid coordinates don't use the same scale as the point coordinates. So you need to convert the 4 points of the rectangle into grid coordinates first, and do all the math in grid coordinates.

Comment: I still don't get it. The X and Y you use are all in grid-space, or in normal space? I have a function ToGridCoordinate(Vector2), and calculate the grid coordinates for all the corner points. I don't know what the min/max X is and how to get your points.

Can you maybe provide a pseudocode?

Comment: @sollniss In your drawing, the XY values `1.843` `4.554` and `2.64` all make it appear that grid coordinates **are** normal space coordinates. But the `-1.2` appears to be off by 1, seems like it should be `-0.2`. My answer assumed that all coordinates are grid coordinates, but if they aren't, then you need to convert to grid coordinates first.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is supposed to be -0.2, didn't notice. In the drawing the two coordinate system are aligned, yes. So In the general case I convert to grid coordinates, then compute the four sides and then traverse them with your formula?

Comment: Is M still the same for cell sizes different than 1? Like say, all cells are 1.3x1.3 units.

Comment: Cells are always 1x1 in the cell coordinate system. If they're a different size in normal space coordinates, that affects the transformation of the 4 points of the rectangle from normal coordinates to cell coordinates, but nothing else.