# What values are passed to the fragment shaders for inner fragments of a triangle when only having defined values per point

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have the following very basic shaders.

**Vertex shader:**

```
attribute vec4 a_foo;

varying vec4 v_foo;

void main()
{
    v_foo = a_foo;
    gl_Position =  a_foo;
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
varying vec4 v_foo;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_foo.xy);
}
```

The attribute `a_foo` I provide as a vector for each point. It is passed to the fragment shader as `v_foo`.

When my mesh consists of only single points (`GL_POINTS`) it is clear that I can expect `v_foo` to match `a_foo`. But what happens in case of having a triangle (`GL_TRIANGLES`) consisting of three points, when I have much more fragments (texels?) than points?

Will `a_foo` get interpolated for fragments between the fragments of the points?
Does this happen for all types of `varying` that I can pass between vertex and fragment shader?

Answer (score 1):

Each primitive is rasterized so every "visible" (not clipped) pixel of your triangle will invoke a fragment shader and pass values interpolated (because you used `varying`) from the 3 triangle control points based on fragment relative position to the 3 control points.

The interpolation might be linear or [perspective corrected linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping#Perspective_correctness) depends on your OpenGL pipeline settings.

For more info about rasterization of convex polygons see:

- [how to rasterize rotated rectangle in 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061146/how-to-rasterize-rotated-rectangle-in-2d-by-setpixel/19078088?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C69.1117#19078088)

However gfx cards use barycentric coordinates and test all pixels inside BBOX if inside polygon or not by simple winding rule test to take advantage of parallelism...